# print text with typewriter effect, clear after each sentence on loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to achieve a typewriter effect with my text where each sentence (h1 tags) gets printed then the text is cleared and the second sentence gets printed. Once the second or third sentence is done printing it should clear and start printing the first sentence again on loop.

I am unable to clear the first sentence, all text just gets stacked, also the word 'the' is not appearing.

Any ideas how to proceed? I would like to keep the text in the HTML so I can re-use the script on different pages.

**JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/b33uhLL2/**

HTML:

```
<div id="typewriter">
  <h1>This<br> is<br> the<br>first<br><span class="highlight">sentence</span></h1>
  <h1>This<br> is<br> the<br>second<br>sentence</h1>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function setupTypewriter(t) {
  var HTML = t.innerHTML;

  t.innerHTML = "";

  var cursorPosition = 0,
    tag = "",
    writingTag = false,
    tagOpen = false,
    typeSpeed = 200,
    tempTypeSpeed = 0;

  var type = function() {

    if (writingTag === true) {
      tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }

    if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "<") {
      tempTypeSpeed = 0;
      if (tagOpen) {
        tagOpen = false;
        writingTag = true;
      } else {
        tag = "";
        tagOpen = true;
        writingTag = true;
        tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
      }
    }
    if (!writingTag && tagOpen) {
      tag.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }
    if (!writingTag && !tagOpen) {
      if (HTML[cursorPosition] === " ") {
        tempTypeSpeed = 0;
      } else {
        tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 50;
      }
      t.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }
    if (writingTag === true && HTML[cursorPosition] === ">") {
      tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 50;
      writingTag = false;
      if (tagOpen) {
        var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
        t.appendChild(newSpan);
        newSpan.innerHTML = tag;
        tag = newSpan.firstChild;
      }
    }

    cursorPosition += 1;
    if (cursorPosition < HTML.length - 1) {
      setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
    }

  };

  return {
    type: type
  };
}


var typer = document.getElementById('typewriter');
typewriter = setupTypewriter(typewriter);
typewriter.type();
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to DIY this, or are you just looking for a solution? Because there's loads of libraries out there that already do this

Comment: i want to keep the text inside the HTML and most libraries put the text inside JS

Answer (score 0):

You may have some luck with `GreenSock`.

You could use `.from` inside a timeline. Here's a starting point using two headers.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('div')
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1')
const h2 = document.querySelector('h2')

const typewriterTimeline = new TimelineMax({
  onStart: () => container.classList.remove('hidden')
})

typewriterTimeline
  .add(TweenMax.from(h1, 3, {text: '', delimiter: ' '}))
  .add(TweenMax.from(h2, 3, {text: '', delimiter: ' '}))
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='hidden'>
  <h1>This is the title</h1>
  <h2>This is the subtitle</h2>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/plugins/TextPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

To make this more dynamic, you could loop over your content and generate a timeline.